# Why is the intraday table sometimes missing from the BigQuery dataset?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

My team has linked our Firebase and BigQuery projects and set up the intraday table. However, the table is created unpredictably. I was able to use it yesterday (`events_intraday_20200701`), but it is already noon as of writing this, and there is still no intraday table (`events_intraday_20200702`) in the dataset. (The regular event tables are there, per usual). In the streaming area of the Firebase console, I can see hundreds of events being generated, but cannot query an intraday table to see them in realtime.

I also struggle to find resources clarifying when the table is created besides "raw event data is streamed into a separate intraday BigQuery table in real-time" from
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en. Are there reasons why the table may not be created, or more details about what time during the day I can expect it to exist?

On a related note, is it true that Web events are not supported for the intraday table?

Thanks!

Comment: Which timezone are you using in Firebase and in which timezone are you?

Comment: @rmesteves The Firebase project is New York Time, and I am in Eastern Standard Time (same).

Comment: Is the box "Include streams in export" marked in the importation? In general this integration happens without problems

Comment: I have a similar issue with the intraday table.  I can see about 500 events in Firebase > Analytics > Events.  The intraday table is created but only has a total of 64 events.

Comment: That was not checked, thanks! I still don't see an intraday table, but if this solves the issue by tomorrow, then I will mark this as resolved.

Comment: @RyanGlaspey if it solves your problem let me know if I can post it as an answer

Comment: I noticed the intraday table at about 11:00am EST yesterday, but was not present today. And the issue wasn't that no events were being streamed. It didn't catch either web or mobile events that were showing up in Firebase StreamView